# How to write if condition with using label text (Int) values

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, label

I am getting the dates from the server (response) and that values I am storing in an labels and I want to write a if condition using the labels I want to allow to next Viewcontroller if the used leaves should be greater that total leaves and I am getting error

My condition is as the "total leaves" and "used leaves"  will come dynamically through server and numbers should be like in total 5 leaves (total leaves) if we apply 2 days leaves that will convert into(total leaves) "3" and used leaves label text will replace to 2 like this format it will work and if total leaves is 0  in that condition too error message should appear

my code is

```
 if  ((self.totalLeaves.text) > (self.usedLeavesLbl.text)) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You Dont have leaves to Apply", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                switch action.style{
                case .default:
                    print("Please Enter Details")

                case .cancel:
                    print("cancel")

                case .destructive:
                    print("destructive")
                }}))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ApplyLeavesViewController") as! ApplyLeavesViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

my error is compile error                                                          Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'UIContentSizeCategory'
Construct 'UIContentSizeCategory' from unwrapped 'String' value

Comment: What values "totalLeaves" and "usedLeavesLbl" do have?

Comment: total leaves "2" used leaves "3"

Comment: as it will come dynamically through server and numbers should be like in total 5 leaves (total leaves) if we apply 2 days leaves that will convert into(total leaves) "3" and used leaves label text will replace to 2 like this format it will work and if total leaves is 0  in that condition too error message should appear

Comment: Check updated answer, is it satisfying your conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Just compare by converting the string to int

```
 if (Int(self.totalLeaves.text!)! == 0 || (Int(self.totalLeaves.text!)! < Int(self.usedLeavesLbl.text!)!)) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks some errors came but modified. and  its total leaves less than used leaves                                                                          if  (Int(self.totalLeaves.text!)! == 0 || (Int(self.totalLeaves.text!)! < Int(self.usedLeavesLbl.text!)!)) {

Comment: Welcome @vamsi :)

Comment: Yeah just using part of that after modifying it helped me

Answer (score 1):

Check with below answer!

```
    guard let totalLeaves = self.totalLeaves.text,
        let usedLeaves = self.usedLeavesLbl.text else {
            //totalLeaves or usedLeavesLbl is nil
            return
    }

    guard let intTotalLeaves = Int(totalLeaves),
        let intUsedLeaves = Int(usedLeaves) else {
            //totalLeaves or usedLeaves is not contains integer values
            return
    }

    if (intTotalLeaves == 0) || (intTotalLeaves > intUsedLeaves) {
        //Display your error message here
    } else {
        //redirect to another view controller
    }
```